# CSS only applying to half my list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have been making a website for my local scout group and I am having problems when creating the menu, for a reason I can't determine the css doesn't apply to the first two elements, but does to the last two. is anyone able to help? I think it's because of the hover drop down, but as I say I'm unsure.
Thanks,
Roshan
Have a look on JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="fluid menu" align="right">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sections.php">Sections</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Beavers.php">Beavers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="cubs.php">Cubs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="scouts.php">Scouts</a>                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                USA Trip
            </li>
            <li>
                Forum
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 25px 0 27px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  color: #84a40b;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
ul li:hover {
    background: #4d2177;
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #4d2177; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #672c9f; 
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
ul li ul li ul{
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
ul li ul li ul li{ 
  background: #4d2177; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #672c9f; 
}
ul li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional to write your selectors like `ul li ul li` instead of `ul>li>ul>li` or `.menu>ul>li>ul>li`?

Comment: No, sorry. I've now  changed that, but the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple because your first two items are links, last two are not.

I think they should be all links.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">USA Trip</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Forum</a>
</li>
```

And then add the color to the links.

```
.menu ul li a {
  color: #84a40b;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/3/

Comment: that's weird, it works fine in jsfiddle, but on my site it doesn't. [link](http://test.roshan-b.co.uk/scouts2/header.php)

Comment: I tried adding ".menu" before it but now it applies it even when hovered

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra it looks fine on your site, it's correct that also applies to the hover style, add the color for a:hover if you need a different one.

Comment: Oh, I only refreshed once, oops. Thanks for the help @sdcr.

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra the boilerplate.css sets the default link color to white, so you should set both ul li a {color1} and ul li a:hover {color2} in your custom stylesheet.

Comment: This is what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/5/ but it doesn't seem to work, which line of boilerplate.css is setting it to white, I've tried commenting out 62-76 but it didn't change anything

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra you can simply get rid of `a:link {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}` in main.css

Answer (score 0):

The CSS applies just fine. The difference between the first and the last items is that you have links in the first items.

The links already have their own style, so you would need to style the links in the list also.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an idiot, I applied ">a" to the end of all of the styles and that made it worse, which ones am I meant to apply it to?

Comment: @Roshan. I don't know about the other problem with your code but if you add this line to your CSS it is working fine for me: `ul li a{ text-decoration:none; color:#84A40B }`. https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/1/

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra: Just moving all styling to the links would not give the desired result. Add rules for the links, and move just the styles that you need to override into them, like the text color.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your CSS: `ul li a{ text-decoration:none; color:#84A40B }`. Heres JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the `<a>` not the `<li>`.

This will style all anchors which are somewhere in a list `<ul>`

```
ul a {
    color: YOUR_COLOR;
}
```

The problem is that you are defining the color to the list item `<li>`. You expect that everything in it will have this color. However the default blue anchor `<a>` color is more specific.
So your `<a>` inside `<li>` don't get the `<li>` color since it has it's own blue color.

Answer (score 0):

that's because last two list items doesn't have anchors , just add

```
 ul li a{
        color: #84a40b;
        text-decoration:none;
    } 
ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/q4p1s8yL/4/)